# Spring Boot Redis Template Pipeline Exception Handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I wish to make my pipeline re-try up to 3 times incase it fails to insert into Redis. How can I achieve this my current code is:

```
@Repository
public class MyRedisRepository {

    private final int EXPIRY_TIME = 1000;

    @Autowired
    private final StringRedisTemplate template;

    @Override
    public void setPeople(List<People> people) {
        template.executePipelined(getRedisSetPeoplePipelineAction(people));
    }

    private RedisCallback<Object> getRedisSetPeoplePipelineAction(List<People> people) {
        return connection -> {
            StringRedisConnection stringRedisConn = (StringRedisConnection) connection;
                Expiration expiration = Expiration.seconds(EXPIRY_TIME);
                people.forEach(person -> {
                    stringRedisConn.set(person.getKey(), person.getValue(), expiration, UPSERT);
                });
            return null;
        };
    }
}
```

My thinking is to catch `DataAccessException` and then re-try. But is this the correct exception to catch?

I believe Spring Boot is using Jedis under the hood.

Cheers

Comment: What is your motivation for retries?

Comment: We want all the data in the pipeline to be set it anything fails

Comment: How about wrapping `template.executePipelined(…)` in a `for`-loop with a nested `try/catch` that exits the `for` loop on success? Alternatively, check out the lettuce driver which has transparent reconnect/retry under the hood (it never let's you see I/O Exceptions)